# Editing Word doc from Sharepoint on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, sharepoint

Consider a Word document in SharePoint. I've created this .doc using Word 2007 on a Windows 7 machine. I've then uploaded the document to the SharePoint directory.

[image: Edit]

Editing that document brings the problem. We're presented next with a non-descriptive message box:

[image]

> The document could not be edited. The required application may not be installed properly, or the requested document cannot be opened.

I don't think Office is installed improperly. I've actually used this installation of Word to create the document to begin with.

**Workarounds Tried:**

- 'Repair' Microsoft Office. No different results.
- Open the document normally from SharePoint, just clicking on the document. The Save dialog doesn't show the SharePoint folder at all, but my Win7 Library instead.

**Question**

How can you edit a document in SharePoint using Office 2007 and Windows 7?
Is this an Internet Explorer setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the .doc file extension was associated with WordPad, rather than Word. Saving the document as .docx and re-submitting to Sharepoint was the solution to my problem here.